# Games and accurate timing

Tags: actionscript-3, timing

I am new to Actionscript and making a game to learn its ways. The game relies heavily on timing as it will be spawning enemies timed with music. For example spawn 2 enemies at exactly 1:31 minutes, start firing at exactly 1:32 etc.

An example of ways I have thought to approach was using timers with events.for example: to spawn an enemy I would have have a timer that has timer(100000,0); which when up will active a spawning enemy. Problems with this approach is 1, that would require too many timers and 2, I have heard the timer is not very accurate.

Is there any accurate ways to time many events which won't slow down the game greatly?

Comment: If you want to sync with music, rather than risking your audio falling out of time with a timer, look into an audio-only flv with embedded cuepoints.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that, I did hear that audio can very easily slip out of sync

Comment: You're right about Flash not being too great with timers. Worst case is that it's on per-machine basis. I use an external date check to re-sync the timers (try a local date check?). I find that you lose ~1 second for every minute counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flv with embedded cuepoints

see this links
http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?277542-Cue-Points-flv-embedded
http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Flash_video_component_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Using cuepoints within an FLV is probably the most accurate and consistent way to get your spawns to sync up.

If for some reason, you can't do that, you could call getTimer() to get the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since your application started.  Do a getTimer() lookup every ENTER_FRAME, and if the result is greater than your desired time then spawn an enemy.  I would worry about your Sound object not being in sync with this technique, and there would be very little you could do to fix it.